# polkit rules not recognized raspbian stretch

Tags: raspbian, polkit, udisks

I'm running a raspbian stretch and I want to grant every member of group user the right to mount and unmount usb-pendrives

Therefore I installed: `udisks2`

I created a *.rules file `/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/50-udisks.rules` with the following content:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {


var YES = polkit.Result.YES;
  var permission = {
    // only required for udisks1:
    "org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount-system-internal": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks.luks-unlock": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-eject": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-detach": YES,
    // only required for udisks2:
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.eject-media": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.power-off-drive": YES,
    // required for udisks2 if using udiskie from another seat (e.g. systemd):
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-other-seat": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.eject-media-other-seat": YES,
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.power-off-drive-other-seat": YES
  };
  if (subject.isInGroup("users")) {
    return permission[action.id];
  }
});
```

I restarted the polkit service:

```
systemctl restart polkit
```

When issuing: `udiskctl mount -b /dev/sda1` 
a user is still asked to login as root.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: what is the name for that group user or users?

Comment: in my case it is users

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/507975/5132 .

Answer (score 2):

It seems it's due to the fact that Debian does not yet use the JavaScript style rules files.
You have to place a `*.pkla` file like this in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/53-udisk.pkla`.

contents for a single user called "user":

`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/53-udisk.pkla`:

```
[Enable Controlling of udisk]
Identity=unix-user:user
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount;org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount-system-internal;org.freedesktop.udisks.luks-unlock;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-eject;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-detach;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock;org.freedesktop.udisks2.eject-media;org.freedesktop.udisks2.power-off-drive;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-other-seat;org.freedesktop.udisks2.eject-media-other-seat;org.freedesktop.udisks2.power-off-drive-other-seat
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

This way it is working for me now on raspbian stretch or jessie!

Answer (score 1):

I could apply permission to udisks with the following setting.

/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-udisks.pkla

```
[udisks]
Identity=unix-group:users
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

Reference: https://mxlinux.org/wiki/system/mount-internal-partition-without-using-root-password/

Comment: Welcome to Unix! You could improve the answer by enabling code formatting on the /etc/polkit... URL and the Reference link having an alternate text assigned so it just says the text instead of the whole URL for accessibility.